# How do i parse Google Places Detail JSON file?

Tags: android, json, string, parsing, int

I am a noob to android and i want to parse a google response JSON with the same formatting as the example here:  https://developers.google.com/places/documentation/details.  I'm trying to get the string formatted phone number.  However, when i code to .getString from the array "events" my editor asks for a int index.  I don't understand what is going on.  Any help is greatly appreciated.  Here is my code:

```
try {   
        JSONObject googleObject = StoresNearMe.getJSONfromURL(googleplacedetailapi);
        JSONObject parsedGoogle = googleObject.getJSONObject("results");
        JSONArray  parsedevents = parsedGoogle.getJSONArray("events");
        //thing.setText(googleplacesapi);
        if(parsedevents.equals("") ){
            Toast.makeText(FindDealer.this, "No nearby locations", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }else{
            String phonenumber = parsedevents.getString("formatted_phone_number");
            thing.setText(phonenumber);   
      }            
  } catch (JSONException e) {
      Log.d("log_tag","JSON parsing error - Google Places Api:" + e.getMessage());
  }
```

Comment: If i understand it correctly, since it's an array, it may contain multiple phone numbers. If you are sure that there's only one phone number, try 0 index

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`formatted_phone_number` is in `results` json object, not in `events` json array.

Change the line:

```
String phonenumber = parsedevents.getString("formatted_phone_number");
```

to

```
String phonenumber = parsedGoogle.getString("formatted_phone_number");
```

You might read something about json structure on json.org.